# using a wcf service with a custom config path

Tags: wcf

I am struggling with calling a WCF service inside an assembly library with a custom config file. The WCF service runs within a Citrix Xen Server environment which is probably the cause of the problem.

I have setup a console application that references the assembly library and calls a public method inside that library that connects to the WCF Service endpoint and display the data derived from a call of a WCF function inside a Win Forms Datagrid.

Right now I am setting the config path for the current app domain inside the constructor of the Win Forms class 'E2ADokumente' that is displayed by the assembly library:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(E2ADokumente));
var assemblyFilePath = assembly.Location;
var assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFilePath);
var dllName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".dll.config";
string configPath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, dllName);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configPath);
```

The WCF proxy is build like so:

```
WSTrustChannelFactory channelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory("STSEndpunkt")
```

"STSEndpunkt" is the name of the endpoint and is defined in the config file.

All works if I run the code locally but the config file won't be located if I run the same app within the Terminal Services environment. The error messages states that "STSEndpunkt" cannot be found.

It works inside the Terminal Services environment though if I run the assembly library inside a new app domain. But having a separate layer and calling method through reflection is a little too much overhead so I am searching for a simpler solution.

How can I set the path for a config file with the WCF configuration details inside an Assembly library that runs within Terminal Services?

Building the WCF channel setup in code is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after a lot of google-fu.

The setting of the config path for the assembly library works if its done inside the static constructor of the class.

```
static E2ADokumente()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(E2ADokumente));
    var assemblyFilePath = assembly.Location;
    var assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFilePath);
    var dllName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".dll.config";
    string configPath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, dllName);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configPath);
}
```

After that the config file for the WCF service was loaded by the assembly library.

I have no idea what differences the fact that the application is running within Terminal Services contributes but at least this is a simple fix.